# Who were the first and second persons to use Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

In episode 132 of *Naruto*, in the middle of the fight between Naruto and Sasuke, there is a flashback in which Itachi asks Sasuke to obtain Mangekyou Sharingan, and if he is able to obtain it, he will be the third guy to use it.

Who were the first and second persons, as both of his father and Tobi had Mangekyou Sharingan and he himself was using Mangekyou Sharingan?

Comment: Wasn't it Indra Otsutsuki to use MS for the first time against his brother Ashura?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is Obito, then known as Madara Uchiha.
The second one is Shisui Uchiha, a very good friend of Itachi. Shisui gave one of his eyes to Itachi, the other one was stolen by Danzo.

Comment: what do you mean *known as Madara Uchiha*? did you maybe mean *known as Tobi*?

Answer (score 2):

I think in this context he means that Sasuke will be the *3rd person alive* to be able to use Mangekyou Sharingan. Since Itachi is one, and Madara the other.

Comment: how come that Itachi was aware that Madara is alive?

Answer (score 0):

The first and second person who able to use Mangenkyou Sharingan is Uchiha Madara and his brother Uchiha Izuna. They obtained Mangenkyou Sharingan during shinobi world war and battles between Senju and Uchiha clan. So far, it is not known how they obtain it, but for sure they must kill their close relative to obtain Mangenkyou Sharingan.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Specify specific anime episodes and manga chapters, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the first people to obtain the Mangekyou Sharingan were Hagoromo Otsutsuki, the Sage of Six Paths, and Indra Otsutsuki, his eldest son. Hagoromo awakened his Mangekyou Sharingan when he stabbed Hamura while he was being controlled. He awakened this before he was even known as the Sage of Six Paths.. After Hagoromo gave birth to Indra, they were the only shown beings to possess a Sharingan, obviously before the Uchiha Clan formed. Indra then killed his two closest followers after the successor of Ninshu was chosen, thus awakened his Mangekyou Sharingan.

Indra awakened his MS after killing his closest followers, Hagoromo awakened his MS (and Rinnegan) after he stabbed a controlled Hamura. This was before Madara and Izuna even existed, let alone the entire Uchiha clan. Thus they were the first to use Mangekyou Sharingan.

Indra and Hagoromo were the first to ever awaken a Mangekyou Sharingan, but why Hagoromo can use his MS abilities (such as susano'o) with his Rinnegan active, yet doesn't possess a Tomoe-Rinnegan is completely unknown.